# Split cells containing both strings and numbers into separate cells in excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a datasheet with a column of information that contains both strings and numbers, like this:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Word 1 words 1 group of words -2 |
| Wordy 6 Wordo 5 |
| Worde 8 worduu 10 Words Wordos 4 |

My goal is to format this cell so that a new column is started before and after each number without separating words, so it looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Word | 1 | Words | 1 | Group of Words | -2 |
| Wordy | 6 | Wordo | 5 |  |  |
| Worde | 8 | worduu | 10 | Words Wordos | 4 |

Is there any way to do this?

I initially tried to use the Text to Columns function with the space as the delimiter, but this would separate all of the words into separate columns as well as the numbers, and I need the words to stay untouched. I've been looking into a way to set up a concatenate function that looks for each number and places a "," before and after every number in the cell so that I can use "," as the delimiter, but the function is becoming quite complicated and I'm not even sure if this is the correct method to use.

My current function works like this:

```
{=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1)-2,""))),",")}
```

This is successful in searching for the first instance of a number and writing the first set of words with a "," and no space, but I don't know where to go from here to have it recognize how many numbers are in each cell and continue the concatenate function from the middle. I notice that this particular method will eventually have a mistake whenever there is a repeated number such as if 1 is repeated in the cell, it will only list the position of the first instance of 1.

It will also give an issue with offsetting the position of the concatenation whenever there is a negative value, and possibly a few more issues could come about in the future that I don't recognize yet.

The list is quite long so I wouldn't be able to just deal with the Text to Columns function separating each group of words by manually repositioning each column that messes up.

I'm hoping there is a simple way that I'm overlooking to have a formula or layout recognize a number and surround that number with a delimiter of my choice so that I can use the Text to Column function, ideally without VBA because I know nothing about how to read VBA, but if it is impossible without VBA then I will take whatever solution someone can come up with.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Sorry for not including this. I am using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Add a column of lists of splits
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Splits", (r)=> 
            List.Accumulate(
                List.RemoveFirstN(Text.Split(r[Column1]," "),1),
                {Text.Split(r[Column1]," "){0}},
                (s,c)=> if 
                (try Number.From(List.Last(s)))[HasError] and
                (try Number.From(List.Last(s)))[HasError] = (try Number.From(c))[HasError]
                  then List.ReplaceRange(s,List.Count(s)-1,1,{List.Last(s) & " " & c})
                  else s & {c})),

//Remove the original data column
    #"Remove Column1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Column1"}),

//get a count of the eventual number of columns
    #"Column Count" = List.Max(List.Transform(#"Remove Column1"[Splits], each List.Count(_))),

//create semi-colon delimited strings from the Lists; than split that into columns
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(
        #"Remove Column1", {"Splits", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
        
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Splits", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv),#"Column Count")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I am getting an error.
I selected my range Data-> From Table as all of column A, selected Advanced Editor, noted the source was "Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content]," pasted the code in and renamed the source to match my data, hit done, but receive an error:
"Expression.Error: The import Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?"

Comment: When I select "go to error" it highlights the "Added Custom" line in applied steps and says "Expression error: The name 'Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly."

Comment: @Noodle It seems as if that function was not added until after 2016 and yours was never updated by MS. I'll look at the problem again tomorrow. Sorry.

Comment: @Noodle I've replaced that `Splitter` function with others that I am pretty sure were present in 2016. See if it works for you.

Comment: Wow fantastic, this worked. Thank you again for looking into this problem. I need to learn how to do this sort of thing in the future...

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2016 it's not easy, but still possible:

Paste this in a different cell in the 1st row and drag to the right/down:

```
=IFERROR(
         IF(
            ISODD(COLUMN(A1)),
            INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IFERROR(IF((CODE(MID("  "&$A1,ROW($1:$99),1))=32)+(CODE(MID("  "&$A1,ROW($1:$99),1))>57),MID("  "&$A1,ROW($1:$99),1),"|"),"")),"||"," "),"|"," "),"  ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$9)*99,99)),
                  (COLUMN(A1)+1)/2),
            INDEX(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM(CONCAT(IFERROR(IF((CODE(MID(" "&$A1,ROW($1:$99),1))>44)*(CODE(MID(" "&$A1,ROW($1:$99),1))<58),MID(" "&$A1,ROW($1:$99),1)," "),"")))," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$99)*99,99)),
                  COLUMN(A1)/2)),
         "")
```

Let me try to explain it..

The function splits the cell string into single characters and checks the `CODE` of that character. (The table below is helpful for explaining the logic).

[image]

For the numerical values I check if the code is between 48 and 57 (see table).

For the text characters I check if the characters equal 32 (space character) or are greater than 57 (the largest code for a numerical character).

Now for the splitting by numerical values, I will explain it with the 3rd example you gave, which was the hardest, because of space separated words and numerical values more than 1 character.

So for retrieving the text strings I replace spaces or numerical characters with `|`,
next I substitute duplicate `||` with single `|` and than the single `|` with a space character.
The original text/space characters in the string are now surrounded by extra spaces by the substitution we just made, meaning these are separated by at least 2 spaces unlike the words that were not separated by numbers, that still have 1 space in between.

We than added a double space in front of the string to include the first word and split that using MID/REPT:

[image]

The orange cell is the start, next the green cells are the substitution steps and the grey cell is the result array.

For the numerical split I used a slightly different logic:

I kept the characters that had a code between `42` (minus sign) and `57` last code for numerical character (`9`) and substituted the rest of the characters by a space, so if we TRIM it, the numberical characters (and minus character) are separated by a single space character.

If we split that using MID/REPT we get:

[image]

Since Excel 2016 doesn't allow spills like shown in the screenshots, we need to INDEX the array results.

Answer (score 1):

You may try-

```
=DROP(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),IF(ISNUMBER(--x),"|"&x&"|",x))),"|")),,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I do not have the textsplit and textjoin functions. Is there any way to do this using functions on the 2016 version?

Answer (score 1):

Just another fun alternative:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=PY(
    import re
    l=[re.split(r'(?:\s+(?=-?\d)|(?<=\d)\s+)', s) for s in xl("A1:A3")[0]]
    [a+['']*(max(map(len,l))-len(a)) for a in l]
)
```

Or, if you don't care for N/A# errors:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=PY(
    import re
    [re.split(r'(?:\s+(?=-?\d)|(?<=\d)\s+)', s) for s in xl("A1:A3")[0]]
)
```

---

Excel 2016 (been a while for me), try:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&CONCAT(IF((ISNUMBER(MID($A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))),3)*1)+(ISNUMBER(MID($A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1)))-1,1)*1)))*(MID($A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))),1)=" "),"</s><s>",MID($A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))),1)))&"</s></t>","//s["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"")
```

And confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag this to the right and down.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to have access to python functions in my version of excel...

Comment: @Noodle, shame. Excel365 is a lifesaver at times. It's been a while since I made CSE-entered formulas this long, but I edited in an option for you =)

Comment: `FILTERXML()` always does the job, also OP dont have to worry about the use of web, since they are already using `Excel 2016`

Comment: Thank you for your solution for this problem. When I use this, I needed to change the Concat( function to Concatenate( to get anything other than the returned error "", but after doing so, the only thing I get in each of the first column is the first letter of each cell. Also all columns to the right of the cell with this equation end up empty. I did make sure to enter it as an array. Thankfully, Ron's method seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and came up with a formula works with **`Excel 2010+`** onwards, however I would go with the methods outlined by **[Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld)** Sir using `POWER QUERY` or by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir using `PYTHON` as it would be really easier and truly lifesaver. Also, with `MS365` formulas definitely its easy but since there is no option, hence `POWER QUERY` would be goto guy!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99),LEN(IF(LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",))<4,$A1&"  ",$A1))
 -LEN(SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",))<4,$A1&"  ",$A1)," ",)))," ",REPT(" ",99),4)," ",
  REPT(" ",99),3)," ",REPT(" ",99),2)," ",REPT(" ",99),1),COLUMN(A$1)*99-98,99))
```

---

The above given formula is truly large and kind of ugly, but cant help it, works with the given data in the OP!

Comment: Thank you for your take at the solution! Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work in the instance of my cell having more than 3 numbers (it can get up to 10 different values that are in the cell). It seems that Ron's solution works for me though!